# Wordpress: cannot configure Wordpress to use CloudSQL

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-sql

I'd like to migrate my WP website database to Google Cloud SQL and have created a database at my google cloud sql Instance.

I've already imported the sql file stored in bucket to relevant database and already configured Wordpress wp-config.php to use CloudSQL as well.
But the website did not run as expected.
Here is the wp-config file:

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'sukhavat_blog' );
/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', '***' );//username is my newly created MySQL user account
/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '***' );//username is my newly created MySQL user account password
/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', '35.247.134.165:3306' );//this is IP from Overview tab of my Instance
```

When I checked the debug log, it shows this:

```
[22-Jun-2020 10:43:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in /home2/sukhavat/domains/sukhavati.xyz/public_html/wp-includes/option.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/sukhavat/domains/sukhavati.xyz/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php(69): get_option('WPLANG')
#1 /home2/sukhavat/domains/sukhavati.xyz/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php(136): get_locale()
#2 /home2/sukhavat/domains/sukhavati.xyz/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php(1207): determine_locale()
#3 /home2/sukhavat/domains/sukhavati.xyz/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php(1168): _get_path_to_translation_from_lang_dir('wp-optimize')
#4 /home2/sukhavat/domains/sukhavati.xyz/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php(1137): _get_path_to_translation('wp-optimize')
#5 /home2/sukhavat/domains/sukhavati.xyz/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php(1238): _load_textdomain_just_in_time('wp-optimize')
#6 /home2/sukhavat/domains/sukhavati.xyz/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php(175): get_translations_for_domain('wp-optimize')
#7 /home2/sukhavat/domains/sukhavati.xyz/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php(25 in /home2/sukhavat/domains/sukhavati.xyz/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 73
```

I dont know what's wrong now...

Thank you...

Comment: Your DB setup is fine. It might have to do a with a Caching plug-in see: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-to-undefined-function-wp_cache_get-after-update-to-5-3-3/

Comment: No... when I go back to local database, it works fine... when I checked the Network tab of the console: it shows 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I understand that you are trying to connect with a public IP right?
Did you followed the steps on the Google documentation to connect with public IP?
And also, could you connect to you instance from a local machine?

The documentation is in [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip)

I believe that you could be missing something else... like the "authorizing networks" step or something in between.

Answer (score 0):

You need add the port another way, for example:

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'sukhavat_blog' );
/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', '***' );//username is my newly created MySQL user account
/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '***' );//username is my newly created MySQL user account password
/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', '35.247.134.165' );
define( 'DB_PORT', '3306' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue.
I checked everything (IP addresses, Authorized Networks, Database etc.). Everything was correct.
I believe it just is not possible to connect a WordPress website hosted by a different platform to Google Cloud SQL Instance.
You have to migrate to Google Cloud Engine.